# Defining a class in c++

Tags: c++, class, error-handling

When I try to run this program, I get an error saying:

> "fatal error: sales_item.h: No such files or directory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_item.h"
int main()
{
Sales_item book;
std::cin >> book;
std::cout << book << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

What's that supposed to mean? The book I read, c++ primer 5th edition, has taught me to define a class this way.
Is it wrong?
Why can't I run this program?

Comment: It means it can't find the sales_item.h file. That's not a standard header or anything. You presumably have to make it and drop it in the same folder.

Comment: Show your `Sales_item.h` file (which should perhaps be named `sales_item.hh`); also show how you compile your example, and tell which compiler and system are you using.

Comment: That is not a class definition.

Comment: You created `sales_item.h` header file?

Comment: How do I show it? Please elaborate. I'm very new to all this.

Comment: @Judas: Are you using `Visual Studio`? if yes, which version?

Comment: No. Using Codeblocks. Although, I do have Visual Studio 2012. Not really comfortable with it.

Comment: In `Visual Studio`, you may easily create the header file and cpp file of a class by selecting `'Add Class'` from the `Project` menu. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is wrong.

let's say that this code is in a file named `MyFile.cpp`, then your piece of code assumes the declaration of the class is in the file `"Sales_item.h"` in the same folder as the `MyFile.cpp` source file.

The #include is in fact a copy/paste directive, that copy the content of the specified file in the current file, and the compiler compiles it. Now the `Sales_item.h` file doesn't exist, and the compiler gives you an error that it can't find it.

**The correct way to declare and define the class:**

```
#include <iostream>


// #include "Sales_item.h"
// What should be in the "Sales_item.h" file

#include <string>
class Sales_item
{

public:
    Sales_item(std::string itemName) //constructor
    {
        m_Name = itemName;
    };

    const char * GetName()
    {
       return m_Name.c_str();
    }

private: //member variables

    std::string m_Name;
};


// End "Sales_item.h"


int main()
{

    std::string bookName;
    std::cin >> bookName; //requires the user to type a string on the command prompt

    Sales_item book(bookName); //construct the object
    std::cout << book.GetName() << std::endl; // retrieve & print the item name on the command prompt
    return 0;
}
```

**Another point** is that in C++ generally your classes are declared in a header file (.h/.hpp), and defined in a (.cpp) file. In my example, the class is both declared and defined in the same file to simply. That is a different topic than what your question asks for, but read more on "declaration vs definition" in C++ if you want more information on how to code with good coding practices in C++.

The best approach, but more complex, would be to code my example like this: https://gist.github.com/jeanmikaell/5636990.

Over any book, I'd recommend you to read this concise tutorial before programming: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Comment: Do I just store this as .cpp in the directory of the code I want to run?

Comment: Yes, all in one .cpp and compile/run it. However, using the best coding practice, my example would coded like this: https://gist.github.com/jeanmikaell/5636990. Over any book, I'd recommend you to read this concise tutorial before programming: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

It means the compiler can't find a file named `Sales_item.h` that you've asked it to include into the file you're compiling.

At a guess, the book wanted you to create a file with that name, and save it into the same subdirectory where you have the source file above stored.

Comment: Hey, Jerry! How do I create the file?

Comment: @judas: You've apparently skipped over an important part of the book. Maybe go back and review where they taught how to do that sort of thing.

Comment: @C. Lang, I don't think I have. Just re-read the last few pages. Nothing about this.

Comment: There are plenty of [tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/89-class-code-and-header-files/)s available.

Comment: @judas: that's going to depend on what editor you're using, the host OS, and things like that -- stuff you *almost* need somebody looking over your shoulder to tell you how to do the first time (or else a book that insists you configure your system up a particular way, and gives very specific directions assuming you've followed its configuration).

Comment: Okay, turns out, I was getting ahead. The book hasn't got there. It was just an example they were showing, and wasn't meant to be understood already.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](http://suite101.com/article/how-to-create-a-cpp-class-a97702).

Few lines from this link:

How to Declare a Class

Classes may be declared in the files where they will ultimately be used. However, it is much better practice to define them in separate files. The classes can then be reused easily in any new application. However, there are actually 4 stages to creating and using a C++ class:

1. create a header file containing the class declaration
2. create a C++ file containing any functionality for the class
3. call the header from the C++ application being developed
4. compile the files containing the class functionality and the new application

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way to do this

**Sales_item.h**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Sales_item {
 public:
     Sales_item(){};
     ~Sales_item(){};
          friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &in, Sales_item &si);
            friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, Sales_item &so);
private:
     std::string name;

};

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream &in, Sales_item &si)
{
     in >> si.name;
     return in;
}
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, Sales_item &so)
{
     out << so.name;
     return out;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_item.h"
int main()
{
  Sales_item book;
  std::cin >> book;
  std::cout << book << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

source : https://sites.google.com/site/ypwangandy/tv

Answer (score 0):

I had tried several ways but didn't work. I finally created a file named Sales_item.h by myself, copying and pasting [Sales_item.h](https://github.com/amidvidy/learning/blob/master/cpp-primer/Sales_item.h) to that file. Make sure your cpp file and Sales_item.h file are under the same folder.